# Receiving notification while app is in foreground - (pie 28)

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to building apps with android so please excuse the stupidity.

I get notifications to my app when it is in the background but not while it is in foreground which I am trying to get the notification for both.

What is happening now is that when I receive a notification to my app when it is in foreground it crashes the app.

I do understand how android handles those 2 events differently when they are in those two different states so I have to modify my `onMessageReceived` to handle that data. Here is what I have so far

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.d("msg", "onMessageReceived: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        String channelId = "Default";
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle()).setAutoCancel(true).setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()).setAutoCancel(true).setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "Default channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }

}
```

Side Question: I am not sure if this part of my code is correct `manager.notify(0, builder.build());` It is my understanding that `0` is a CHANNEL_ID of some sort so I am not sure if `0` is the correct value to use.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:stopWithTask="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

It is also my understanding in order to get `onMessageReceived` to process the `send` that I need to not use `notification` and instead use `data`. So I am sending my data like this with php.

```
$notification = [
    'title' => $title,
    'body' => $message,
    //'icon' =>'myIcon',
    'vibrate' => 1,
    'sound' => 'default'
];

$fcmNotification = [
    'registration_ids' => $token,
    'data' => $notification
];

json_encode($fcmNotification));
```

**Logcat**

```
2018-12-31 12:36:26.416 22775-22850/com.domainname.main.domainname D/msg: onMessageReceived: null
2018-12-31 12:36:26.419 22775-22850/com.domainname.main.domainname E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-MyFirebaseMessagingService
    Process: com.domainname.main.domainname, PID: 22775
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage$Notification.getBody()' on a null object reference
        at com.domainname.main.domainname.MyFirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived(MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:31)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzd(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzc.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

So at this point I am not sure of the issue is how I am sending the data or my code in my `MyFirebaseMessagingService.java`. Any ideas?

**UPDATE SOLVED**

Ok I figured it out and it was primarly how I was sending the data. I had to change my php to this

```
$notification = [
    'title' => $title,
    'body' => $message,
    //'icon' =>'myIcon',
    'vibrate' => 1,
    'sound' => 'default'
];

$extraNotificationData = [
    'title' => $title,
    'body' => $message,
    //'icon' =>'myIcon',
    'vibrate' => 1,
    'sound' => 'default'
];

$fcmNotification = [
    'registration_ids' => $token, //single token
    'notification' => $notification,
    'data' => $extraNotificationData
];
```

For those of you who can't figure out how to play the default sound for a notification when using `onMessageReceived` when sending `data` you can add this to your FirebaseMessagingService extension (Mine was `MyFirebaseMessagingService.java`) `.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))`

Answer (score 1):

@Cesar Please, could you copy and  paste the log cat part where the crash took place? Then we can look there to see the exact error.

Comment: Yeah @MArcelo I figured it out from looking at the Logcats like you suggested and updated my answer with a solved. I cant mark this as the answer, but it did point me int he right direction to getting it solved so I +1